# Points in multiple polygons using R

Tags: r, gis, point-in-polygon

Currently I have two data.frames, one of polygons `(poly.x, poly.y, enum)` and one of points `(pt.x, pt.y)` where `enum` is the id of the polygon. I am trying to determine which points belong to which polygons so I get a data.frame of `(pt.x, pt.y, enum)`.

My first attempt uses `point.in.polygon` from the `sp` package and `lapply` functions to find which polygon(s) the point belongs to. While my code works, it takes a *long* time on large data sets.

My second attempt uses `over` also from the `sp` package, cobbled together from questions on gis stackexchange. While it is *much* faster, I cannot seem to get the correct output from `over` as it is a dataframe of `1`s and `NA`s.

Below I've included a simplified working example (`npoly` can be changed to test the speed of different methods) as well as my working attempt using `sp::point.in.polygon` and nonsensical output from my `sp::over` attempt. I'm not fussed which method I end up using as long as it's fast.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#-------------------------------------------
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)  # sample plots
library(dplyr)    # bind_rows(), etc
library(sp)       # spatial data
# Sample data
npoly = 100
#  polygons
localpolydf <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(0, 1, 1, 0), npoly) + rep(0:(npoly-1), each = 4),
  y = rep(c(0, 0, 1, 1), npoly),
  enum = rep(1:npoly, each = 4))
#  points
offsetdf <- data.frame(
  x = seq(min(localpolydf$x) - 0.5, max(localpolydf$x) + 0.5, by = 0.5),
  y = runif(npoly*2 + 3, 0, 1))
# Sample plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = enum), 
               localpolydf, fill = NA, colour = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), offsetdf)

#-------------------------------------------
# Dplyr and lapply solution for point.in.polygon
ptm <- proc.time() # Start timer
#  create lists
offsetlist <- split(offsetdf, rownames(offsetdf))
polygonlist <- split(localpolydf, localpolydf$enum)
# lapply over each pt in offsetlist
pts <- lapply(offsetlist, function(pt) {
  # lapply over each polygon in polygonlist
  ptpoly <- lapply(polygonlist, function(poly) {
    data.frame(
      enum = poly$enum[1],
      ptin = point.in.polygon(pt[1,1], pt[1,2], poly$x, poly$y))
  })
  ptpoly <- bind_rows(ptpoly) %>% filter(ptin != 0)
  if (nrow(ptpoly) == 0) return(data.frame(x = pt$x, y = pt$y, enum = NA, ptin = NA))
  ptpoly$x = pt$x
  ptpoly$y = pt$y
  return(ptpoly[c("x", "y", "enum", "ptin")])
})
pts_apply <- bind_rows(pts)
proc.time() - ptm # end timer

#-------------------------------------------
# Attempted sp solution for over
ptm <- proc.time() # Start timer
# Split the dataframe into a list based on enum and then remove enum from df in the list
polygonlist <- split(localpolydf, localpolydf$enum)
polygonlist <- lapply(polygonlist, function(x) x[,c("x", "y")])
# Convert the list to Polygon, then create a Polygons object
polygonsp <- sapply(polygonlist, Polygon)
polygonsp <- Polygons(polygonsp, ID = 1)
polygonsp <- SpatialPolygons(list(polygonsp))
plot(polygonsp)
# Convert points to coordinates
offsetps <- offsetdf
coordinates(offsetps) <- ~x+y
points(offsetps$x, offsetps$y)
# Determine polygons points are in
pts_sp <- over(offsetps, polygonsp)
proc.time() - ptm # end timer

#===========================================
# Output
#  Apply: point.in.polygon
> head(pts_apply)
   x   y         enum ptin
1 -0.5 0.2218138   NA   NA
2  4.0 0.9785541    4    2
3  4.0 0.9785541    5    2
4 49.0 0.3971479   49    2
5 49.0 0.3971479   50    2
6 49.5 0.1177206   50    1
user  system elapsed 
4.434   0.002   4.435 
# SP: over
> head(pts_sp)
1  2  3  4  5  6 
NA  1  1 NA  1 NA 
user  system elapsed 
0.048   0.000   0.047
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using `over` is to use `sf::intersection` as the sf package is becoming more and more popular.

Getting the data into sf objects took me a little bit of work but if you are working with external data you can just read in with  `st_read` and it will already be in the correct form.

Here is how to approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# convert into st_polygon friendly format (all polygons must be closed)
# must be a nicer way to do this!
localpoly <- localpolydf %>% split(localpolydf$enum) %>% 
lapply(function(x) rbind(x,x[1,])) %>%
lapply(function(x) x[,1:2]) %>%
lapply(function(x) list(as.matrix(x))) %>%
lapply(function(x) st_polygon(x))

# convert points into sf object
points <- st_as_sf(offsetdf,coords=c('x','y'),remove = F)

#convert polygons to sf object and add id column
polys <- localpoly %>% st_sfc() %>% st_sf(geom=.) %>% 
mutate(id=factor(1:100)) 

#find intersection
joined <- polys  %>% st_intersection(points) 


# Sample plot
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=polys) +
geom_sf(data=joined %>% filter(id %in% c(1:10)),aes(col=id)) +
lims(x=c(0,10))
```

Note that to use geom_sf at the time of writing you will need to install the development version of ggplot.

plot output:
[image: plot output]

Answer (score 1):

`over` returns an index of points inside a geometry. Perhaps something like this:

```
xy <- offsetps[names(na.omit(pts_sp == 1)), ]

plot(polygonsp, axes = 1, xlim = c(0, 10))
points(offsetps)
points(xy, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! However, I was mainly after a column name of polygon IDs (`enum`) next to `xy`, ie for any `(x, y)` which polygon (in this case a square) is it in?

Comment: @Alwin next to `xy`? Can you make a smaller reproducible example and show (perhaps color by hand?) what polygons you're after?

Answer (score 1):

After having another look, I realised Roman did `pts_sp == 1` because I only had 1 ID for all of my squares, i.e. when I did `ID = 1`.

Once I fixed that, I was able to a column with `ID = enum`. To handle points in multiple polygons I can use `returnList = TRUE` and add additional lines to convert the list to a data.frame but it isn't necessar here.

```
# Attempted sp solution
ptm <- proc.time() # Start timer
# Split the dataframe into a list based on enum and then remove enum from df in the list
polygonlist <- split(localpolydf, localpolydf$enum)
# Convert the list to Polygon, then create a Polygons object
polygonsp <- sapply(polygonlist, function(poly){
  Polygons(list(Polygon(poly[, c("x", "y")])), ID = poly[1, "enum"])
})
# polygonsp <- Polygons(polygonsp, ID = 1)
polygonsp <- SpatialPolygons(polygonsp)
plot(polygonsp)
# Convert points to coordinates
offsetps <- offsetdf
coordinates(offsetps) <- ~x+y
points(offsetps$x, offsetps$y)
# Determine polygons points are in
pts_sp <- over(offsetps, polygonsp)
pts_sp <- data.frame(
  x = offsetps$x, y = offsetps$y,
  enum = unique(localpolydf$enum)[pts_sp])
proc.time() - ptm # end timer
```